# Resuming outdoor water after winter

Tags: outdoor, winterizing

I am about to install these valves (is this the right word?) to resume having water in the garden.

[image: valve]

Once installed, these will be brass on brass. I'm concerned that I will not obtain a watertight seal.

Does brass, in this particular setting, provide water tightness, or is there some kind of sealing material I need to use?

I think the bleeder part (is this the right word?) is only needed when winterizing. There is nothing I need to do with it at springtime—other than ensuring it itself does not leak.

Comment: it looks like the threads have some pipe dope on them. a couple of wraps of PFTE / Teflon tape on the threads will seal it up. the small rolls at the home stores are less than a dollar. that will seal it up if there is not enough left on the threads.

Comment: @EdBeal , you keep making answers in comments. While I support making a sketch of an answer in comments, since I do that when I don't feel like writing a full answer (or don't have a full answer), this is perfectly good to copy, paste and post as an answer - so you should do that.

Comment: @EdBeal Could you move your comment to become an answer? "Teflon tape" are the keywords I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested made this an answer. it looks like the threads have some pipe dope on them. a couple of wraps of PFTE / Teflon tape on the threads will seal it up. the small rolls at the home stores are less than a dollar. that will seal it up if there is not enough left on the threads. – Ed Beal May 26 at 19:02   delete

Answer (score 0):

Ed's right.  Or if you have a washer for a garden hose laying around, you can put that on before screwing it in.  I know they sell about 20 of these for a few dollars at the big box home improvement stores, it's handy to keep them around the house.

Comment: Uh, no, Tapered pipe threads and straight hose threads seal by very different mechanisms. A hose washer won't help a pipe thread joint, and pipe dope or tape won't help a garden-hose joint.